# How to read and set custom properties in Ready API at test suite level

Tags: groovy, ready-api

I have a project with multiple test suites and each test suite have their own custom properties.So my question is: Is there a way to read from one file and set custom properties in different test suites.

Answer (score 0):

To read property value store in Test Suite from groovy script

def val = context.expand('${#TestSuite#PropertyName}')
log.info val

And you can update the value but i am not sure if it is possible to add a custom property at Run Time

To update value at runtime you can use
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue('PropertyName',val);